# Can't call puts with subclass of Ruby Hash

Tags: ruby, hash, tostring

I have built a subclass of Hash, and whenever I call `puts` with an instance of my class as an argument, I get the following:

```
> puts data
TypeError: can't convert Reporting::Search::Data to Array (Reporting::Search::Data#to_ary gives Reporting::Search::Data)
```

Does anyone have any idea what to do? I'd like it to output a string representation of a Hash, just like calling `puts` with an ordinary Hash would do.

My class is really simple:

```
  class Data < HashWithIndifferentAccess
    def method_missing meth, *args, &block
      if meth.to_s =~ /=$/
        send :[]=, meth.slice(0...-1), *args
      elsif args.empty?
        fetch meth, Data.new
      else
        super meth, *args, &block
      end
    end

    def compact!
      delete_if do |k,v|
        v.compact! if v.is_a?(Data)
        v.blank?
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: What is `HashWithIndifferentAccess`?

Comment: It's a Hash subclass provided by Rails in which keys of type `String` and `Symbol` are considered identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue is to do with your use of `method_missing`.

When you call `puts`, it tries to output the object in a human-readable form, so it calls `to_ary` on the object. However, you haven't defined `to_ary` on your class, so it falls back to `method_missing` where it gets confused and fails.

Define, `to_ary` as a stub, and I'm not getting the error anymore.

```
def to_ary
end
```

This is one of the many pitfalls of metaprogramming in Ruby!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, either write a `to_s` method. Or you could see what the `.inspect` instance method gives you, though it may not be very useful!

Have you tried adding a to_s method like this?

```
def to_s
  super.to_s
end
```

Also, it may not be the only reason you're having issues, but you've named your subclass `Data` which is already a class in Ruby.

Comment: I tried defining `to_s` before posting this question. I get the exact same error. As for calling `inspect`, that doesn't raise an error, but it imposes an unexpected requirement on other programmers to know that they can't call puts on my model.

Comment: I'm not sure as a developer that I would expect for `puts` to work in all cases. (Although, I suppose I wouldn't expect it to throw an exception!) I would expect to be able to write `puts object.inspect` though. I will have a play around, this has intrigued me!

Comment: @MaxWoolf: I'm pretty sure `puts` works all the time. It outputs `#<ClassName:object_id>` if no `to_s` method is defined. I'm guessing something else is at work in OP's question.

Comment: Although possibly helpful, this answer doesn't answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You are violating Ruby's type conversion protocols in various ways.

First off, your object responds to `to_int`, `to_float`, `to_str`, `to_ary` etc. without actually *being* an integer, a float, a string or an array. The three letter (*ahem* f-l-o-a-t *ahem*) versions of those type conversion methods are supposed to be used *only* in the case where the object in question really absolutely positively *is* an integer, float, string or array and is just not represented as an instance of `Integer`, `Float`, `String` or `Array`.

However, your object isn't an `Array`, it's a map. So, it should only respond to `to_hash`, if at all.

And secondly, the return value of `to_int`, `to_float`, `to_str`, `to_ary` etc. should be an instance of the `Integer`, `Float`, `String` or `Array` class.

So, you are implementing methods that you shouldn't even be implementing in the first place *and* you are returning the wrong value from them. Doing that for something as deeply ingrained in the core of Ruby as its type conversion protocols is bound to wreak all sorts of havoc of which you are only seeing the beginning.